# Как образуется слово "податливый"?

Tags: словообразование

В словаре значение прилагательного ***податливый*** определяется через значение глагола  ***поддаться***, но в словарной статьях для  глаголов *поддаться/поддаваться*  оно не указано.

И почему происходит **усечение приставки ПОД**? Или это приставка ***ПО***, и тогда прилагательное имеет корень глагола ***дать***?

Какова схема образования слова?

ПОДАТЛИВЫЙ,  1. **Легко поддающийся обработке**. П-ая порода, земля. П. металл. // Легко поддающийся воздействию, не оказывающий сопротивления. П-ая загородка. 2. **Легко подчиняющийся влиянию; уступчивый, сговорчивый.** П. характер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По приведённому определению из толкового словаря нельзя проследить словообразовательную схему для слова **податливый**. Даже суффикс **-лив-** в ней не отражён. Цель толкового словаря — дать наиболее простое и понятное толкование слова.

Мне представляется вполне правдоподобным способ образования этого слова, соответствующий этимологии, описанной в Викисловаре (со ссылкой на Фасмера, в котором, впрочем, я этого не нашёл): **податливый** от податься, из **по-** плюс **дать**.

Толкование слова можно тогда представить таким образом:
**податливый** — склонный подаваться при воздействии: давлении, обработке, влиянии и т. п.

Comment: Суффикс ЛИВ здесь очень даже  у места, так как имеет значение склонности к действию (хвастливый, говорливый, бережливый).  Так о каком действии здесь идет речь? ПОДАТЬСЯ,  св. 1. Сдвинуться с места, подвинуться, уступив напору. Бревно подалось. Дверь под нажимом подалась.  Рычаг не подался.  Тогда схема: податься - податливый?

Comment: Конечно ЛИВ к месту! Вы же видите, как я дал толкование слова. Звучит точнее с точки зрения словообразования/этимологии, но чуть менее понятно (хотя и означает в точности то же). Да, конечно, схема "податься — податливый". Не могу понять, что у Вас вызывает сомнение. Мне кажется, этот вариант совершенно естественный и вполне очевидный.

Comment: Сомнения вызвал словарь, в котором "податливый"  определяется через "поддаться", а не через "податься" Спасибо за ответ, у меня больше нет причин для сомнений.

Comment: Ссылкам Викисловаря на Фасмера точно доверять не стоит; у них полный беспорядок.

Comment: @Aer Да, я обычно перепроверяю. В данном случае я ответ оформил как своё мнение, но всё же решил дать ссылку на Викисловарь — не в качестве ссылки на авторитетный источник, а лишь поскольку он послужил основой для этого мнения.

Answer (score 0):

Податливый -  послушный, слабовольный, то есть, слушающийся чужих указаний и легко передающий свою волю постороннему.   Семантика слов подать и поддать несколько различная, несмотря на общий корень "дать", и различие это создают именно приставки. Например: подать можно шляпу, пальто и молотк, а поддать - парку в бане(значение - добавить).
Вывод: усечения нет, по - это самостоятельная приставка. Пример: послушать - подслушать, послушный,  подслушанный.

Comment: Податливый - легко поддающийся (согласно словарю).  Возможная схема: поддаться - податливый, но тогда приставка  ПОД усечена.  Другая схема: дать - податливый. Но значение прилагательного не определяется через глагол "дать".